# opacity&position of PDF´s element, created with inkscape, is faulty when converting PDF to a Word file

Tags: inkscape, svg, pdf, microsoft-word

The opacity and position of my element in my PDF file, which I created with inkscape, disappears when I convert the PDF to a Word fileConverting a PDF, which is created with inkscape, into an Word file.

I tried to change the element on the SVG file with converting the element to a path or group. I tried to convert the element to a PNG and insert it to word directly as a watermark, but it is no satisfactory solution.

SVGhttps://jmp.sh/s/DD5odAJbEIU8EJTtQNB8
PDFhttps://jmp.sh/s/SWP2rgpbswbRUDYW7XeH
Wordhttps://jmp.sh/s/0EuFof1kQBFLfpWhZVaE

What do I have to do so that I can use the PDF in Word so that the SVG settings of the elements are not manipulated in an unwanted way?

Comment: Not sure if that would really be possible.  Maybe ask on SuperUser.  MS Word isn't graphic design software, so it's kinda off-topic here.